# URLEncoding from Objc to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, url-encoding

We are using following URL encoding in Objective C now we are migrating to swift .what will be the equivalent encoding for below ObjC to swift 3.

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString {
    NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
    const unsigned char * source = (const unsigned char *)[self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen((const char *)source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = source[i];
        if (thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' || 
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should generate exactly the same result as your Objective-C code.
(Should compile and work as expected in both Swift 3 and 4.)

```
extension String {
    var urlEncoded: String {
        var output = ""
        for thisChar in self.utf8 {
            switch thisChar {
            case UInt8(ascii: " "):
                output.append("+")
            case UInt8(ascii: "."), UInt8(ascii: "-"), UInt8(ascii: "_"), UInt8(ascii: "~"),
                 UInt8(ascii: "a")...UInt8(ascii: "z"),
                 UInt8(ascii: "A")...UInt8(ascii: "Z"),
                 UInt8(ascii: "0")...UInt8(ascii: "9"):
                output.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(thisChar))!))
            default:
                output = output.appendingFormat("%%%02X", thisChar)
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
print("https://www.google.es".urlEncoded) //->https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.es
```

Some points:

- You can iterate on each UTF-8 byte with `for thisChar in self.utf8`
- To convert a string literal (actually a UnicodeScalar Literal) to a `UInt8`, you can use `UInt8(ascii:)`
- You should better consider using `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` with proper `CharacterSet` and pre/post-processing

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it this way -

```
extension String{

    func urlEncodedString() -> String {
        var output = String()
        let source: [UInt8] = Array(self.utf8)
        let sourceLen: Int = source.count
        for i in 0..<sourceLen {
            let thisChar = source[i]
            if thisChar == UInt8(ascii: " ") {
                output += "+"
            }
            else if thisChar == UInt8(ascii: ".") || thisChar == UInt8(ascii: "-") || thisChar == UInt8(ascii: "_") || thisChar == UInt8(ascii: "~") || (thisChar >= UInt8(ascii: "a") && thisChar <= UInt8(ascii: "z")) || (thisChar >= UInt8(ascii: "A") && thisChar <= UInt8(ascii: "Z")) || (thisChar >= UInt8(ascii: "0") && thisChar <= UInt8(ascii: "9")) {
                output += "\(Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(thisChar))!))"
            }
            else {
                output += String(format: "%%%02X", thisChar)
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile in Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3.3) nor Swift 4 (Xcode 9 beta 5).

Comment: Updated the answer now.

Comment: `print("https://www.google.es".urlEncodedString())` ->104116116112115%3A%2F%2F1191191194610311111110310810146101115. You need to fix: `output += "\(thisChar)"`.

Comment: Thanks @OOPer for the tip. Tried it now and changed it. Noticed now that it becomes similar to your answer. Upvoting it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this swift 3 compatible code. I've tested it in a playground and works fine.

```
extension String {
    func urlEncodedString() -> String {
        var output = ""
        for thisChar in self.utf8 {
            if thisChar == UInt8(ascii: " ") {
                output += "+"
            }
            else if thisChar == UInt8(ascii: ".") ||
                thisChar == UInt8(ascii: "-") ||
                thisChar == UInt8(ascii: "_") ||
                thisChar == UInt8(ascii: "~") ||
                (thisChar >= UInt8(ascii: "a") && thisChar <= UInt8(ascii: "z")) ||
                (thisChar >= UInt8(ascii: "A") && thisChar <= UInt8(ascii: "Z")) ||
                (thisChar >= UInt8(ascii: "0") && thisChar <= UInt8(ascii: "9")) {
                output += "\(Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(thisChar))!))"
            }
            else {
                output += String(format: "%%%02X", thisChar)
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let url = "https://www.google.es".urlEncodedString()
print(url)
```

Comment: Your code generate something like this `https%2D0C0%2D180%2D200www.google.es`, this is not the expected result for `"https://www.google.es".urlEncodedString()`.

Comment: You are right!. I've updated the code and works fine now.

Comment: Confirmed. By the way you (and also @kapsym) can replace the second line of `output += ...` to `output += "\(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(thisChar))!)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace below code (Swift 3.1.1):

```
func urlEncodedString() -> String {
    var output = String()
    let source: [UInt8] = UInt8(utf8)
    let sourceLen: Int = strlen(CChar(source))
    for i in 0..<sourceLen {
        let thisChar: UInt8 = source[i]
        if thisChar == " " {
            output += "+"
        }
        else if thisChar == "." || thisChar == "-" || thisChar == "_" || thisChar == "~" || (thisChar >= "a" && thisChar <= "z") || (thisChar >= "A" && thisChar <= "Z") || (thisChar >= "0" && thisChar <= "9") {
            output += "\(thisChar)"
        }
        else {
            output += String(format: "%%%02X", thisChar)
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as the old code of kapsym, which did not compile in Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3.3) nor Swift 4 (Xcode 9 beta 5).